# Setting landing page for different users

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am Using Liferay 6.1CE.

I can able to set my default landing page to a site in control panel.
But in my portal 2 sites are there,two users are there.
For eg: userA is a member of siteA,simularly UserB member of siteB.

How can i redirect the users to their site after login.

What can i do?

Comment: On what condition you are deciding if userA has to be redirected to siteA and userB to siteB?

Comment: I don't know how to check and where to check, userA is dedicated to only siteA and userB is dedicated to siteB.

Answer (score 0):

I guess 2 sites you mean two communities. Anyway you need to create `post login action` where you'll check your conditions and redirect where needed.

Comment: ok..where this java file is placed?  do you have any idea about the coding to fullfill this..

Comment: Ok. Create simple Web App with  class com.coolApp.auth.PostLoginAction extends Action. Place login.events.post=com.coolApp.auth.PostLoginAction in portal-ext.properties. At this stage your user is logged in and you may redirect him wherever you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the Liferay hook for your custom login post action. Please have a look at :

[custom action using hook](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/performing-a-custom-action)

on how to create the hook.

In the hook, you can identify the looged in  user based on your search criteria and redirect to the relevant community.